# What setting should I set on my amp and guitar to copy the sound for the choice from TLOU? have a Fender Champion 20 and Epiphone SG Special P-90

Tags: electric-guitar, amplifiers

just a new guitar player learning his favourite melody from a game and was wondering how to recreate that sound, What setting should I set on my amp and guitar to copy the sound for the choice from TLOU? I have a Fender Champion 20 and an Epiphone SG Special P-90. Would really appreciate an answer and am really keen to get it perfect because I love the song so much.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Got a feeling this doesn't comply with the remit for this site, so it may get closed. Have a read of the Help Center. Guitar and amp settings are only part of any sound.

Comment: I agree this isn’t really on topic - very close to a transcription request. That said, I suggest you consider the fact that you’ll never be able to *perfectly* imitate a sound, even if you can get close. This is because some important ingredients that make up a recorded guitar tone include the player, the recording equipment used, and the settings used on the recording and mix processors during recording and mixdown. Also, experimenting with your equipment to get it to sound as close as you can is a valuable personal journey that you should explore on your own.

Comment: I agree with @ToddWilcox, but you might be able to stay on the right side of the rules by adding a text description of the kind of sound you're looking for. A good enough description might allow for an answer that at least points you in the right direction, without requiring answerers to transcribe the recording. It also might be acceptable to reference a well-known song with a similar sound; that would increase the likelihood others might have the same question in the future.